# I am trying to get multiple columns of data from a row if one of the columns in the row equal today date

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

```
import pandas
import datetime
file = "BT_Schedule_04_27_2020_PM.xlsx"
df = pandas.read_excel(file, sheet_name="BT Schedule")
today = datetime.date.today()
ttudates = df["TTU Date"]
site = df["BLC ID"]


for date in ttudates:
    if date == today:
      print(date)
```

So this gets the date I want which is like 8 rows out of 5000 total. I want to be able to just grab the whole row which has today date in that specific column. Keep in mind there are multiple columns with dates so I cannot just grab a row that contains that date.

[image]

Comment: use a boolean filter `df[df['date'] == pd.Timestamp('today')]` this will return the entire df matching your condition

Comment: Do I put this under the for loop?

Comment: Nope, ditch the for loop the boolean applies in a vectorised manner so it handles the looping for you in more efficient manner. Pandas underyling api tries to avoid loops as they are slow

Comment: print(df[df['TTU Date'] == datetime.date.today()]) I've tried several variations of this and the output just gives me all the columns in a list. but not the 8 rows of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, avoid `for` looping across values of a pandas Series to extract scalar values. Instead run a boolean filter to return a subset of rows with all columns.

However, the pandas `datetime[64]` (a numpy type) cannot be directly compared to a datetime object like `datetime.date.today()`. Therefore, your output is an empty data frame that dumps out list of columns in console.

To return a non-empty data frame, consider simple adjustments for proper comparison using `Series.dt.date` or `strftime` of date time:

```
sub_df = df[df["TTU Date"].dt.date = today]

sub_df = df[df["TTU Date"] = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]

print(sub_df)
```